# Using biblatex - having trouble getting it all working

Tags: biblatex

I've been trying to get it all setup for a while but though the errors have stopped I can't actually get any references working.

Here's the references file :

```
 32 @book{wrong,
 33         author          = {Mr Writer},
 34         title           = {My First Novel},
 35         year            = {2012}, 
 36         publisher       = {Harold & Mike},
 37         location        ] {London
 38 }
```

Here's how the reference displays in text (wrongii was a different reference):

[image]}

Here's the code from the text that's calling the reference :

```
  I'm trying a different way with this line \parencite{wrong}
```

I've also tried to print this Bibliography at the bottom of the page to no effect using :

```
\printbibliography
```

I've been rattling about various sites (including here) and can't seem to find the answer, any help much appreciated.

EDIT

This is my MWE that seems to display the same behaviour :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
This is some text that I'm going to try and 'cite' using the bib file thing.\cite{wrong}

That didn't work, maybe this will \parencite{wrong}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here's the contents of the references.bib file :

```
  1 @book{wrong,
  2         author          = {Mr Writer},
  3         title           = {My First Novel},
  4         year            = {2012},
  5         publisher       = {Harold \& Mike},
  6         location        = {Leamingtion}
  7 }
  8 
  9 
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
~
```

I'm not sure if this is a Texmate setting, I've read things about the backend = bibtex setting and tried that too (it didn't work). I want to have it in author year style, but to start I guess it'd be nice to just have something on there

Options within Texmaker for compiling :

[image]

This seems to have worked :

[image]

Here's the error message that I'm currently getting :

```
    This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian) The top-level auxiliary

file: dbmain.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: title.aux I found no \citation commands-

--while reading file dbmain.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file 

dbmain.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file dbmain.aux (There were 

3 error messages)
```

Apparently I'm meant to use `nocite{}` ?

Sorry this post is ridiculously convoluted :(

Comment: What's with the odd square bracket in the `location` field? Regardless, your problem is most likely as a result of `&` in the `publisher` field. Use `\&` instead.

Comment: argh, missed the bracket and forgot about escaping the ampersand thanks... Fixed those,the problem is still there though.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to post a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. In the link there's a discussion on how to provide a bibliography-related MWE that uses [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents).

Comment: I'll try and make one now - thanks @Werner

Comment: @Werner I've edited the original post

Comment: Your compilation sequence should be (pdf)LaTeX > biber > (pdf)LaTeX > (pdf)LaTeX. Are you compiling with biber? For example, see [What to do to switch to `biblatex`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/5764) and [`biblatex` for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/5764).

Comment: thanks @Werner, I've read those posts actually and still a bit unsure, my heads probably expired though.I'm not sure If I'm compiling with Biber as it's done through Texmaker, looking at the options there are a string of different choices, added image to OP.

Comment: The first option you selected doesn't include any bibliography-related compilation (like BibTeX or biber). The second option - mentioned as Bib(la)tex - includes this compilation, which made it work.

Comment: thanks @Werner, still being weird, kicking up errors for images now instead, using the second command didn't work either. My heads fried, going to have to leave this for the evening. Thanks for your help

Comment: attached error to OP

Comment: The "error message" points to you using Bibtex and you should be using biber. I'm [asking in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19131048#19131048) if there are any TexMaker users who might be able to help.

Comment: Why do you have all those numbers at the beginning of lines in you `.bib` file?

Comment: @cfr it was just copied out of vim